# HP DV7 Beats Audio alsa.base Modification. What should be the line?

Tags: sound, alsa, soundcard, speakers

My laptop has 2 front speakers + 2 next to screen + 1 subwoofer.

- If I don't edit alsa.base I get 2 speakers under LCD.
- If I put this in alsa.base, i get:  `$ options snd-hda-intel model=ref`

I do get sound from 2 front speakers + subwoofer, but don't get the sound from speakers under LCD.

- If I put: `$ options snd-hda-intel model=hp`

I get 2 + 2 speakers "muffled" but not the subwoofer. Anyone could help?

Answer (score 1):

I am also on the DV7 model with beats audio. I used following line (like you did):

```
 options snd-hda-intel model=ref
```

After that ofcourse you reboot, but then you should go to your sound preferences. There you can choose for either "Analog output" or "Analog headphones" on the output tab. This trick worked for me to enable all 5 speakers.

There are 2 downsides though. If you plug in headphones, some speakers will keep playing, and the sound quality is absolutely not like it is when playing under Windows.

If you would discover a better solution, please keep me posted!

Answer (score 0):

Using the following command you might have chances to find out the supported model of your sound device.

```
zless /usr/share/doc/alsa-base/driver/HD-Audio-Models.txt.gz
```

There you can find out possible values for model.

Comment: Still no luck. New BIOS, tried 'options snd-hda-intel model=auto' and still no luck.        P.S. With the new BIOS the laptop does not start with dimmed LCD anymore (although F2 and F3 does not set the brightness anymore). And still did not install fglrx - last time did not install properly (not at all) and had to reinstall :(((, so haven't been brave enough to f... it up again. NVIDIA in my previous laptop was fine.

Answer (score 0):

The following is what I did to set up Beats Audio on the HP Envy dv7t-7200 (Jan 2013). This model has 3 speakers total.

You need installed:

- acpid
- alsa-utils

1. Create or edit `/etc/modprobe.d/acpi-base.conf`, and insert the following line:

   ```
   options snd-hda-intel model=ref
   ```
2. As root, create the following files:

   ```
   /etc/acpi/events/headphone
   /etc/acpi/headphone.sh
   ```
3. Open `/etc/acpi/events/headphone` for editing, and edit such that the entirety of the file is this:

   ```
   event=jack/headphone
   action=/etc/acpi/headphone.sh %e
   ```

   Save the file.
4. Open `/etc/acpi/headphone.sh` for editing, and add the following:

   ```
   #!/bin/bash
   case $3 in
     "plug"  ) amixer set Front mute;;
     "unplug") amixer set Front unmute;;
   esac
   ```

   Save this.
5. Make the script executable:

   ```
   sudo chmod u+x /etc/acpi/headphone.sh
   ```
6. Enable the acpi daemon at startup in whatever way is appropriate for you; put 'acpid' in a startup script somewhere, start it yourself at boot every time by executing acpid . In my case, Arch Linux `systemctl enable acpid`
7. Reboot. Rock out.

- The filename for the alsa-base.conf may be different. Use what is present and working.
- In step 4, you may need to change 'Front' to whatever alsamixer has designated to your speakers. If there are multiple commands which should be issued, best bet is to include them separately:
  `"plug" ) amixer set Master mute; amixer set Front mute;;`
  etc.

The intent is that the steps concerning the acpi handler and script be conflated with whatever steps the user (such as W. Goeman) took to enable their sound so that headphone detection is simulated. Hopefully this helps the OP.

This model is becoming increasingly common and the solutions available are poor, incomplete, and rare.

Answer (score 0):

I added options `snd-hda-intel model=hp-dv7-4000` to alsa-base.conf and it worked for my HP DV7 in the past, but lately I've found it is better and easier to use the hdajackretask tool. You can find great info online on how to install and use the hdajackretask tool to enable the LFE internal subwoofer.